# ¿Por Que al Guardar los datos en sql me dicen que los valores de la llave primaria son duplicados?

Tags: sql, vb.net

¿Por que al momento guardar los datos a sql server me dice que los valores de la llave primario son duplicados? el campo es NumeroFactura de tipo Nvarchar(15)
Si 1) NO hay registros duplicados y
2) y a pesar del error siempre me guarda los datos pero me cierra el programa, Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Private Sub btnguardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnguardar.Click
        Dim conexion As String
        conexion = *"Server=DESKTOP-LA851OJ\JEFFRYSQL;DataBase= SIClinicaRubi; integrated security= true"*
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = conexion

    Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("Insert Into Facturacion Values('" & txtnumerodefactua.Text & "', '" & txtidentidad.Text & "', '" & txtnombre.Text & "', '" & dtfecha.Value & "', '" & txtvendedor.Text & "',   '" & txtmedico.Text & "','" & txtnumerocita.Text & "' ,'" & txtpreciocita.Text & "', @Codigo1, @Nombre, @Cantidad,  '" & txtisv.Text & "', @Precio, '" & txtTotal.Text & "')", cn)
    cn.Open()

    Dim fila As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow

    For Each fila In DataGridView1.Rows
        adaptador.Parameters.Clear()
        adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo1", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("Columna1").Value))
        adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("Columna2").Value))
        adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("columna3").Value))
        adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precio", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("columna4").Value))

        adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    MsgBox("Los datos han sido guardados con exito")

End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cual es la clave primaria de tu tabla? no me digas que es el numero de factura, que siempre pasas el mismo...

Comment: Hola! Por favor, sigue las recomendaciones que te hacen en el otro comentario. Verás que, por ejemplo, es necesario que indiques con qué datos estás probando (qué datos tiene la tabla cuando pruebas y qué datos intentas insertar cuando lanza esa excepción). También serviría saber cómo está definida la tabla. Todo esto lo puedes añadir **editando** la pregunta y, ojalá, como texto (así no nos pones a transcribir datos desde una imagen)

Comment: Para que les llegue la notificación, debes etiquetarlos @JeffryCruz entonces, puede que ese valor ya esté en tu base de datos y es ese el conflicto que te genera. Ya que, al ser la clave primaria esta no se debe repetir

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo es que ese es el problema que no hay ningun valor repetido desde que empece a registrar los datos me genera el error

Comment: @gbianchi Si es el Numero de Factura, alguna segerencia

Comment: Para facturacion, se usa una tabla cabecera y una tabla de detalle con los items de la factura. De ahi tu error. La solucion es arreglar la base de datos y todos los procesos